# .htaccess: How to rewrite all urls to index.php excepting urls to one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite all urls to `index.php` excepting for urls inside `localhost/src/...`

This is the `htaccess` I've been using so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Nevermind I just came up with a solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/src
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

However I would still like to know if there is a better way of doing it

Comment: Certainly other variants are possible, but your solution is perfectly all right.

Comment: You should put your "solution" as an _answer_ (and later accept it). Helps other readers and removes the question from the unanswered question queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the update as an answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/src
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```